# How can you use the value of one cell to index into a column in excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create several sets of graphs with numeric values on the Y-axis and time values on the x-axis. The row numbers are located in cells and I would like to use them as an index when I enter the data into the "Series values" box when making a graph.

The current equation for the X-axis (time values) is =Sheet1!$B$2944:$B$3408 and ideally it would be something like =Sheet1!$B$(value from cell):$B$(value from cell). I have tried to use the MATCH and INDEX functions in the series values box but I keep getting "function not valid". So those may not be appropriate or I might not be entering them right. I am not sure how else to go out about this problem.

Comment: So what did you put in index()? or match()? Showing what did not work may help us help you. There are also many examples of the use of index() on here.

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,ValueFromCell):INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,ValueFromOtherCell)`

Comment: Perfect as mentioned by @ScottCraner Sir. I have used this approach in Excel Graphs earlier to make series dynamic .

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for your help and sorry I dont think I am explaining this well. I think just need to find a way to index a specific rows in a column something like =INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(A1,$B:$,0): INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(A2$B:$,0). But that gives a #VALUE! error.

Where I want to the value of A1 in column B to the value of A2 in column B. Lets say B contains values 1:10 and A1 is 3 and A2 is 9. I want the formula above to then provide numbers 3:9. In Matlab I know how to get this returned as an array but I dont know how to do that in excel.

Comment: Your first match has "$B:$" but needs something like "$B:$B" and the second has the same error as well as the comma is missing between the first and second argument.